# Some sentence construction with feel Like

Tags: sentence-construction

Some sentence construction with feel Like
1.Feel like +verb ing

*I feel like dancing (the speaker has a desire to dance )
Feel like something means have a desire for something. It implies desire and it's weak and passive way to express desire. I'm quite familar with this structure.
But ,
2.feel like +to +verb or
 feel like +to be

For example ,
*what would it be like to live forever ?
*what would it feel like to touch a human brain ?
*what would it feel like to climb the mount Everest ?
**what does it feel like to climb the mount Everest ?
*what does depression feel like ?

Now , I'm not understanding what 'feel like 'means in the above sentences (questions ).
 I'm also not understanding why 'would' is used there in the place of 'does ' ? 
Please also explain me about "feel like +to +verb or
 feel like +to be" sentence structure?

Comment: You seem to mix three grammar issues together: a) *I feel like VERB-ing*; b) *What does/would it feel like to VERB-phrase?*; and c) the difference between *does* and *would* in b). A hint on b): consider its affirmative equivalent, i.e., *It feels/would feel like ____ to VERB-phrase.*

Comment: Yes, i've mixed but no one is understanding my points while answering my question. . . They'v missed something.

Answer (score 1):

'feel like' is not a weak and passive way to express desire. It's a normal way to express a desire.

I feel like eating a sandwich.

(But: I feel like you hate me.)

'would' is used because it's a hypothetical question. You're not about to do it.

'does' is used if it might actually happen.

Do we have to go to school today?

Comment: Actually happened ? Do you mean it's used for past experience? And what about "feel like+ to+verb ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma See edited answer.

Comment: I'm asking what about feel like to +verb ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma Not an option. feel like + ing

Answer (score 1):

The example sentences, when stated, express "curiosity". It doesn't necessarily mean that it has to be experienced, rather, the speaker ponders on what something (particularly an activity/circumstance/experience) feels like.

Comment: Actually happened ? Do you mean it's used for past experience? And what about "feel like+ to+verb ?

Comment: I'm asking what about feel like to +verb ?

Comment: Hi, you may check chown's answer here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57006/i-feel-like-to-eat-vs-i-feel-like-eating

Comment: But, feel like+v is possible in question,

*what would it feel like to climb the mount Everest ?

Comment: Could you please tell me?